# Cómo detener script si If statement es true

Tags: javascript

Hay preguntas similares por la red pero no he podido encontrar algo específico que funcione para mi problema (o si se puede hacer).

Tengo una función que tiene que hacer varias cosas pero que si la primera letra de `(str)` es una vocal, no hay que hacer nada más que añadir "way" a la `(str)`

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
 var vocales = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
 var recogedorConsonantes = []
 var contadorLetrasQuitadas = 0;
 var strVocal = "way";

  //SI el IF stament dentro de este bucle se cumple,
  // quiero que todo lo demás de abajo no se ejecute
 for (var i = 0; i < vocales.length; i++){
  if (str[0] === vocales[i]){
   str = str.concat(strVocal)
   
   }
  else {1==1}}

  // A PARTIR DE AQUÍ detener script si el if de arriba se ha cumplido 


 /*for (letra in str){
  if (str[letra]){


    }
  else if (-------){
  }
        }*/

  return str.slice(contadorLetrasQuitadas, )

}

console.log(translatePigLatin("california"));
console.log(translatePigLatin("glove"));
console.log(translatePigLatin("eight")) // Con esta debería pararse
```

el `str.slice(contadorLetrasQuitadas, )` no hace falta anularlo ya que si el primer if se cumple no se añadirá nada a `contadorLetrasQuitadas` con lo que no modificará nada de `(str)`

He probado a poner break, y "return false" en sitios dónde dicen pero no funciona.

Comment: donde has puesto el break, que dices que no te ha funcionado?

Comment: @MarioGuiber dentro del If statement. No se me ocurre en que otro lado ponerlo claro porque si lo pongo fuera, siempre se parará ahí el script se cumpla el If o no

Comment: Con `return false` dentro del `if` sí que funciona. ¿Por qué dices que no te funciona?

Comment: @Kiko_L es verdad, perdón. Era porque cuando lo probé como sólo me retornaba "false" y no la también la str, asumí que algo andaba mal. Pero justamente claro debe funcionar así. Por lo que veo que me dijo ArianJM en su respuesta, la solución más apropiada aquí es colocar simplemente un return str dentro del If, si se cumple retornará sólo eso y si no se cumple no llegará a ese return y pues hará lo demás y usará el return de abajo del todo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`break` lo que hace es "romper" un bucle. Es decir, sale del bucle. Si estás en un `for`, y quieres terminarlo antes de tiempo, entonces pones un `break`.

`return` lo que hace es "devolver" un valor. Es decir, sale de una función. Si estás en una función, donde quieras que termine, pones un `return`. Puedes acompañarlo de algún valor o variable para que se devuelva.

También tienes `continue`, que en este caso no te servirá, pero te lo explico igual. Lo que hace `continue` es terminar la iteración actual de un bucle. Es decir, si estás en un `for` o un `while`, si pones un `continue` a mitad de la función, cuando se llegue al `continue` se saltará a la siguiente iteración del bucle. O sea, empieza desde arriba con el siguiente valor.

Sabiendo lo que hace cada cosa, podrás usar lo que te convenga en cada momento. En tu caso, por lo que describes quieres un `return`, es decir, algo que salga de la función directamente. Quizá quieras hacer un `return str;` para que devuelva el valor `str`.

El `break` solo terminaría el bucle, pero seguirá dentro de la función.

Answer (score 4):

He probado tu codigo, con `break` no se para, pero probando con `return false`, si que hace lo que necesitas.

Mira este ejemplo adaptado:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
     var vocales = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
     var recogedorConsonantes = [];
     var contadorLetrasQuitadas = 0;
     var strVocal = "way";    
      
     for (var i = 0; i < vocales.length; i++){
      if (str[0] === vocales[i]){
         str = str.concat(strVocal);
                return false; // o return str;
      }
            else {1==1}
      }       
    
     /*for (letra in str){
      if (str[letra]){
    
    
      }
      else if (-------){
      }
            }*/    
      return str.slice(contadorLetrasQuitadas);    
    }
    
    console.log(translatePigLatin("aaaaa")); // muestra aaaaaway
    console.log(translatePigLatin("rrrrr")); // muestra por consola rrrrr
```

Comment: Con `break` sólamente saltarías fuera del bucle `for`

Comment: @Kiko_L exacto :)

Comment: Con tu permiso edito la respuesta y le pongo un snippet :)

Comment: Claro sin problema :)